# Windows start up script runs only partially

Tags: windows, batch-file, virtualbox

In my computer I have running two virtual machines non-stop.
I have set up my computer to auto start when the power goes off and [scheduled a job](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7) to run a batch script when the computer starts that launches those machines (the idea is to run the script whether I'm logged in or not).

The script in question, **vbox_script.bat**

```
@echo off
cd "C:\Users\ME\Desktop"
echo "test test test test" >> testfile.txt
cd "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox"
start /B VBoxManage.exe startvm "Ubuntu 10.04"
start /B VBoxManage.exe startvm "Win7_32b"
start /B VirtualBox.exe
```

The *testfile.txt* file is created, with the expected contents:

```
test test test test
```

But the virtual machines are nowhere to be found. If I manually open the Virtual Box gui, both of them appear as *stopped*.

On the other hand, running the script myself, starts the virtual machines smoothly.

Is there a way to make the machines run automatically when the computer starts?

**NOTE:** The task scheduler reports that the task has been completed without errors.

**EDIT 1:** As @foxidrive suggested, I tried this:

```
start "" VBoxManage.exe startvm "Ubuntu 10.04"
start "" VBoxManage.exe startvm "Win7_32b"
start "" VirtualBox.exe
```

but this didn't work.

Comment: Under what credentials is the scheduled task running?

Comment: @MCND When I created the task I checked the "Run with the highest privileges" box. Then I was asked for my password.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: There is information on scheduled tasks running in a hidden desktop here: https://serverfault.com/questions/251733/task-scheduler-runs-as-hidden-how-to-make-it-visible

Try these commands instead:

```
start "" VBoxManage.exe startvm "Ubuntu 10.04"
start "" VBoxManage.exe startvm "Win7_32b"
start "" VirtualBox.exe
```

Comment: Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: It occurs to me now that I've read info that discusses how scheduled tasks are run in a hidden desktop in modern windows.  You will find info here and links to more information.  http://serverfault.com/questions/251733/task-scheduler-runs-as-hidden-how-to-make-it-visible